# Use inline commands for tclsh

Tags: tcl

Is there such a thing like inline command for tclsh?

Like : `tclsh -e "set a 7 ; puts $a"`

Of course I tried the above and it does not work. But you get the idea?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 3):

With `Expect`, you can achieve this.

```
expect -c 'set a 10; puts $a'
```

The `-c` flag provides a way of executing commands specified on the command line
rather than in a script. Notice that the entire argument to `-c` is **quoted using
single quotes**. This tells the shell not to perform any variable expansion.

The `-c` flag can also be used to execute commands before a script takes control. For example, you can set the variable debug to 1 by invoking Expect from the shell as:

```
expect -c 'set debug 1' myscript.exp
```

Inside the script, you can check the value of this variable:

```
if [info exists debug] {
    puts "debugging mode: on"
else {
    set debug 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used just simple `echo` command with pipe to TCL interpreter.

```
echo 'set a "Hello TCL!" ; puts $a ; exit' | tclsh
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard tclsh doesn't. You can make a small script to do it though:

```
set argv [lassign $argv theUserScript]
eval $theUserScript
```

Call that `docmd.tcl` and run it like this:

```
tclsh docmd.tcl 'puts "Hi from Tcl"; after 1000; puts "Bye from Tcl"'
```

It even handles arguments (and stdin/stdout) correctly:

```
tclsh docmd.tcl 'foreach v $argv {puts [incr i]:$v}' abc def "ghi jkl" m123
```

You'll probably want to use single quotes around any script you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a shell like Bash or Zsh, you can use input redirection, for example (using a "here-string"):

```
tclsh <<<'set a 7 ; puts $a'
```

Note the usage of single quotes do avoid the shell expanding `$a`.